# How to get the data from previous row in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am working on transforming data in Azure data factory
I have a source file that contains data like this:

ABC Code-01
DEF
GHI
JKL Code-02
MNO

I need to make the data looks like this to the sink file:

ABC Code-01
DEF Code-01
GHI Code-01
JKL Code-02
MNO Code-02

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **Fill down** concept available in Azure data factory. The code snippet is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#fill-down).

> **Note**: The code snippet assumes that you have already added source transformation in data flow.

**Steps:**

1. Add **source** and link it with the source file (I have generated file with your sample data).

[image]

2. Edit the data flow **script** available on the right corner to add code.

[image]

3. Add the **code** snippet after the source as shown.

[image]

> source1 derive(dummy = 1) ~> DerivedColumn
> DerivedColumn keyGenerate(output(sk as long),
> startAt: 1L) ~> SurrogateKey
> SurrogateKey window(over(dummy),
> asc(sk, true),
> Rating2 = coalesce(Rating, last(Rating, true()))) ~> Window1

4. After adding the code in the script, data flow generated 3 transformations

   a.  **Derived column** transformation with a new **dummy** column with constant “1”

   b.  **SurrogateKey** transformation to generate Key value for each row starting with value 1.

   c.  **Window transformation** to perform window based aggregation. Here the code add predefined clause `last()` to take previous row not Null vale if current row value is **NULL**.

For more information on Window transformation refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window

[image]

5. As I am getting the values as single column in source, added additional columns in **Derived column** to split and store the single source column into 2 columns.

[image]

6. Substitute NULL values if column value is blank. If it is blank, `last()` clause will not recognize as NULL to substitute previous values.

   `case(length(dropLeft(Column_1,4)) >1, dropLeft(Column_1,4), toString(null()))`

[image]

**Preview of Derived column**: Column_1 is the Source raw data, dummy is the column generated from the code snippet added with constant 1, Column1Left & Column1Right are to store the values after splitting (Column_1) raw data.

**Note**: Column1Right blank values are replaced with NULLs.

[image]

7. **In windows transformation**:

a.  **`Over`** – This partition the source data based on the column provided. As there no other columns to uses as partition column, add the dummy column generated using derived column.

[image]

b.  **`Sort`** – Sorts the source data based on the sort column. Add the Surrogate Key column to sort the incoming source data.

[image]

c.  **`Window Column`** – Here, provide the expression to copy not Null value from previous rows only when the current value is Null

`coalesce(Column1Right, last(Column1Right,true()))`

[image]

d. **Data preview** of window transformation: Here, Column1Right data Null Values are replaced by previous not Null values based on the expression added in Window Columns.

[image]

8. **Second derived column** is added to `concat` Column1Left and Column1Right as single column.

[image]

**Second Derived column preview**:

[image]

9. A **select transformation** is added to only select required columns to the sink and remove unwanted columns (This is optional).

[image]

[image]

10. **sink** data output after fill down process.

[image]